# Recovering source of old version in Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I have multiple versions available in Version Control of my Spreadsheets Script editor. The most recent one is after a complete rewrite of the server side commands and malfunctions terribly at the moment. I have reverted to the last known good version and things are working well at the moment, but something small has come up that requires changing. Here is the issue - i no longer seem to have access to the source of the old version. I can choose to make the old version live, so i figure the source might still be stashed somewhere. Can it be accessed?

Comment: Have you looked at the File History under the File menu?

Comment: Yes, it only lists individual changes and doesn't go very far back at all. In this current case they go back exactly 13 minutes, and i need to go back, like, a week or so. =/